# How can I make this custom fmt formatter code cleaner?

Tags: c++, fmt

I want to write a custom formatter for simple structures inheriting from the existing formatters to access all their options. For example, I've written this for a rectangle:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

template<typename T>
struct rect {
    T x;
    T y;
    T width;
    T height;
};

template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<rect<T>>: formatter<T> {
   template <typename FormatContext>
   auto format(rect<T> c, FormatContext& ctx) const {
       auto out = ctx.out();
       fmt::format_to(out, "[(");
       out = formatter<T>::format(c.x, ctx);
       fmt::format_to(out, ", ");
       ctx.advance_to(out);
       out= formatter<T>::format(c.y, ctx);  
       fmt::format_to(out, "), ");
       ctx.advance_to(out);
       out = formatter<T>::format(c.width, ctx);  
       fmt::format_to(out, " x ");
       ctx.advance_to(out);
       out = formatter<T>::format(c.height, ctx);
       fmt::format_to(out, "]");
       return out;
  }
};

int main()
{
    rect<double> f = {1.0, 2.3445, 3.14, 4};
    fmt::print("{:.2f}\n", f);

    rect<int> b = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    fmt::print("{}\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

It works as expected, but the code inside the `format()` call seems a bit too convoluted.   Q:

1. Is there a way of making it better, or at least cleaner?
2. Is `format_to(...)` the best option for adding those characters to the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the code a bit cleaner as follows:

1. Move the element formatting logic into a separate function/lambda and reuse it in 4 places.
2. Remove redundant namespace qualification since the formatter is defined in the `fmt` namespace.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<rect<T>>: formatter<T> {
   template <typename FormatContext>
   auto format(rect<T> c, FormatContext& ctx) const {
       auto out = ctx.out();
       auto format_element = [&](const T& value) {
           ctx.advance_to(out);
           out = formatter<T>::format(value, ctx);
       };
       out = format_to(out, "[(");
       format_element(c.x);
       out = format_to(out, ", ");
       format_element(c.y);  
       out = format_to(out, "), ");
       format_element(c.width);  
       out = format_to(out, " x ");
       format_element(c.height);
       return format_to(out, "]");
  }
};
```

Full example: https://godbolt.org/z/b8E88d3dG.

`format_to` is a reasonable way to output literal text but you could use `std:copy` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want like this. Note you have to implement `parse` and `format` methods both as per https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types:

```
template < typename T >
struct fmt::formatter < rect < T >>: formatter < T > {
    int floating_point_precision = 0;

    constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context & ctx) -> decltype(ctx.begin()) {
        auto it = ctx.begin(), end = ctx.end();
        if (it != end && ( * it == '.')) it++;
        if (it != end && ( * it >= '0' && * it <= '9')) {
            floating_point_precision = * it - '0';
            it++;
        }
        if (it != end && ( * it == 'f')) it++;

        // Check if reached the end of the range:
        if (it != end && * it != '}') throw format_error("invalid format");

        // Return an iterator past the end of the parsed range:
        return it;
    }

    template < typename FormatContext >
    auto format(rect < T > c, FormatContext & ctx) const {
        auto out = ctx.out();
        if (floating_point_precision == 0)
            fmt::format_to(out, "[({}, {}), {} x {}]", c.x, c.y, c.width, c.height);
        else {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "[({:." << floating_point_precision << "f}, {:." << floating_point_precision << "f}), "
            "{:." << floating_point_precision << "f} x {:." << floating_point_precision << "f}]";
            fmt::format_to(out, ss.str(), c.x, c.y, c.width, c.height);
        }
        return out;
    }
};
```

Comment: Not really. With this solution I loose the formatting (as in the example where `{:.2f}` is used).